# Mail Chimp Error de 401 React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Post en MailChimp 
Esto pasa cuando envio el formulario al querer registar un usuario en Mailchimp, al parecer no esta leyendo la clave ?

```
        mode:'no-cors',
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
       //  credentials:'include',
            headers:{

                Authorization:'auth  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                },

       //headers: headers,
         status:'subscribed',

       //   data:this.state,   

      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json))
      .catch(error => console.log('Authorization failed : ' + error.message));
```

Esto me muestra en la consola del navegador. ¿Que puedo hacer? o ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

[image: El error que me muestra]

Answer (score 0):

El [error 401](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) efectivamente es un error de autenticación. En el modo de autenticación `Basic` (que es el que usa mailchimp) el header tiene que tener esta forma:

```
Authorization: Basic XXXYYY
```

en donde `XXXYYY` es el base64 de *usuario:password*, mailchimp no usa el usuario, puedes poner cualquier string ahí, y en lugar de password usa el `apikey` que ellos proveen, entonces deberías hacer el base64 de `cualquierstring:miapikey`, entonces si tu apikey fuera `XYXYXY` y decides poner apikey como usuario, quedaría `apikey:XYXYXY` y el base64      `YXBpa2V5OlhZWFlYWQ==` entonces el header te quedaría:

```
Authorization: Basic YXBpa2V5OlhZWFlYWQ==
```